# Autofac how to pass configuration settings to base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

Currently I am using Autofac as IoC.
I would like to pass configuration (appsettings) to my base class through I am calling rest services.

current structure is

```
class baseclass{
public baseclass(logger){}
}

class derivedclass : baseclass{
public derivedclass(IService service):base(logger)
{
}
}
```

there are more than 50 classed where i am refering baseclass so dont want to pass configuration for each one.

Can you please help to find solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to change derived constructors to pass through your configuration. So you have some options:

- Inject your configuration to your base class by property
- Live without dependency injection (directly access to ConfigurationManager or some Service Locator pattern).

Although both options are bad practices and I recommend you to inject your configuration through constructors.